# Trying to redirect traffic from AWS cloudfront page to another website url path outside of AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, redirect, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to figure out a way to redirect traffic from my AWS CloudFront site to another domain.

Example:
From –
https://s3.amazonaws.com/s3bucket/page.html
Redirect to –
https://example.com/s3bucket/page.html

I've looked into it, but it seems that the only options are to redirect to another service inside AWS using Route53.
Any suggestions or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: The documentation says that you can point the **origin** to _"Any other HTTP server, running on an Amazon EC2 instance or any other kind of host"_. That includes anything on the Internet that serves HTTP content. Can you tell us more about what you are trying and what specific problem you have experienced?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein What documentation are you looking at?  
I read that I had to do it through Route53. I tried setting IP DNS records, but none of them let me route outside AWS services.

Comment: Sorry, I should have provided a link: [Origin - Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/latest/APIReference/API_Origin.html)

Comment: I posted an updated question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71450840/aws-cloudfront-behaviors-function-not-redirecting