# AWS Cloudfront Behaviors Function not redirecting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Trying to figure out a way to redirect traffic from my AWS CloudFront page to another URL.

I'm currently setting up a "Function" using Cloudfront Functions.
Function code (function name = exampleFunction):

```js
function handler(event) {
    var redirectUrl = "https://example.com"
    var response = {
        statusCode: 302,
        statusDescription: 'Found',
        headers: {
            'Location': { value: redirectUrl }
        }
    };
    return response;
}
```

I publish that and then on my Cloudfront Distribution Behaviors, I create a behavior:

```
 - Path Pattern: /to/my/page.html 
 - Origin and origin groups: example-origin-on-aws  
 - Compress objects automatically: No  
 - Viewer protocol Policy: Http and Https  
 - Allowed HTTP methods: GET, HEAD  
 - Restrict viewer access: No  
 - Cache key and origin requests: Cache policy and origin request policy   
 - Function asssociations: 
   - Viewer request:  
      - Function type: CloudFront Functions
      - Function ARN / Name: exampleFunction
```

I then save the changes.

I also have the following Origin settings:

```
 - Origin domain: BucketName
 - Name: BucketName
 - S3 bucket access:  
    - Yes use OAI:
       - Origin access identity: My OAI
       - Bucket policy: Yes
 - Enable Origin Sheild: No
```

Then when I try to navigate to "https://s3.amazonaws.com/BucketName/to/my/page.html", it still takes me to that page instead of redirecting me to "https://example.com".

Any suggestions to point me in the right direction, or as to what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://s3.amazonaws.com/to/my/page.html seems to be an Amazon S3 URL and not a CloudFront distribution URL. Are you sure you are accessing your CloudFront distribution and not accessing your S3 bucket directly?

Comment: @KaustubhKhavnekar I guess I don't know the difference. But yes, the pages are in an S3 bucket. Someone else set that up and told me it was a cloudfront site.

Comment: The CloudFront function is executed only if you access it from the CloudFront distribution URL. If you access it from the S3 bucket URL, you are accessing the bucket directly using S3's static website hosting feature.

Comment: @KaustubhKhavnekar That sounds right. What should I do in this case?

Comment: 1. Try accessing from the CloudFront distribution URL and see if it works.

2. Consider blocking public access from your bucket and instead only allowing access from CloudFront. You might need to modify your current configuration so that CloudFront's OAI is allowed to access S3 ([Console steps here](https://www.wellarchitectedlabs.com/security/100_labs/100_cloudfront_with_s3_bucket_origin/3_config_cloudfront/))

Comment: @KaustubhKhavnekar Blocking public access just gives locks me out from viewing the page, I want to redirect the page when it's viewed. I had the distribution and OAI already set up.